# Filling next available box with a random number, if first box is occupied - JS

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers

Very new to coding and this website in particular.
I am trying to create a 'Countdown'-style numbers game which involves trying to reach a target number using 6 random numbers. There are two categories of numbers: small numbers (1-10) and large numbers (25,50,75,100). I have created a button for each category which randomly generates a number within that category.
I am able to randomly generate these numbers and populate the first card slot using .onclick method, but I am unable to populate the next 5 card slots; every time I click it randomly generates a number in the same 1st card slot.
The goal is to populate the next card slot every time I click, not all slots at once.
I am using JS. Please see attached code.
Apologies in advance for errors as this is my first post!
HTML:

```js
//Click on small number button to generate a random small number
document.getElementById("small_number_card").onclick = function(){
    genSmallNumber();
}

document.getElementById("large_number_card").onclick = function(){
    genLargeNumber();
}



//FUNCTIONS//

//Generate random small number from array
function genSmallNumber(){
    var smallArray = Array(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10);
    var smallNumber = smallArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*smallArray.length)];
    var cardSlot = 1;
    document.getElementById("box"+cardSlot).innerHTML = smallNumber;
}

//Generate random large number from array
function genLargeNumber(){
    var largeArray = Array(25,50,75,100);
    var largeNumber = largeArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*largeArray.length)];
    var cardSlot = 1;
    document.getElementById("box"+cardSlot).innerHTML = largeNumber;
}
```

````css
```
*{
font-family: monospace, 'Courier New';
}

html{
height: 100%;
background: radial-gradient(circle, white, grey);
}

::placeholder{
color: black;
opacity: 0.5;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 27px;
text-align: left;
}

#container{
width: 600px;
height: 1000px;
background: blue;
margin: 15px auto;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
padding: 1px;
}

#target_box{
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
background: #17bef6;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 15px 45px;
position: relative;
border: 5px solid grey;
}

#target_number_box{
width: 200px;
height: 80px;
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
margin: 14px 150px;
background: black;
border: 5px solid grey;
color: yellow;
}

#target{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
width: 200px; 
}

#start_button{
background: red;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 29px 45px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 5px solid grey;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 50px;
color: white;
}

#start_button:active{
top: 5px;
border-bottom: none;
}

#selection_box{
position: absolute;
background: grey;
height: 60px;
width: auto;
border: 5px solid grey;
left: 50px;
bottom: 14px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
line-height: 60px;
font-size: 30px;
}

.box{
float: left;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
background: blue;
margin-right: 6px;
}

#box6{
margin-right: 0;
}

#whiteboard{
background: white;
width: 550px;
height: 140px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid grey;
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 240px;
}

#working_area{
width: 530px;
height: 120px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
color: black;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e8eded 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8eded 1px, transparent 1px);
background-size: 30px 30px;
line-height: 27px;
resize: none;
}

#card_selection_box{
background: #17bef6;
height: 120px;
width: 550px;
position: absolute;
top: 405px;
left: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid grey;
}

#small_number_box{
float: left;
width: 275px;
height: 120px;
}

#large_number_box{
float: right;
width: 275px;
height: 120px;
}

.number_card{
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
background: blue;
border: 5px solid grey;
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
line-height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.number_card:active{
bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: none;
}

#small_number_card{
position: absolute;
left: 102.5px;
bottom: 10px;
}

#large_number_card{
position: absolute;
right: 102.5px;
bottom: 10px;
}

#counter_box{
background: #17bef6;
height: 120px;
width: 550px;
position: absolute;
top: 405px;
left: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid grey;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 120px;
font-size: 100px;
color: white;
display: none;
}
```
````

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="target_box">
    <div id="target_number_box">
        <span id="target">100</span>
            <div id="start_button">Start</div>
                <div id="selection_box">
                    <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
                    <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
                    <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
                    <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
                    <div class="box" id="box5"></div>
                    <div class="box" id="box6"></div>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="whiteboard">
    <textarea id="working_area" placeholder="Use this area as a working space..."></textarea>
</div>

<div id="card_selection_box">
    <div id="small_number_box">
        Small number<br/>(1-10)
            <div class="number_card" id="small_number_card">
                S
            </div>
    </div>
        <div id="large_number_box">
            Large number<br/>(25, 50, 75, 100)
                <div class="number_card" id="large_number_card">
                    L
                </div>    
        </div>
</div>

<div id="counter_box">
    <span id="counter_value">30</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance! Please avoid JQuery type answers - I'm a noob!

Answer (score 0):

you need to make variable `cardSlot` as global or put it outside the function

```js
var cardSlot = 1; // ==> make it global
document.getElementById("small_number_card").onclick = function() {
  genSmallNumber();
}

document.getElementById("large_number_card").onclick = function() {
  genLargeNumber();
}


//FUNCTIONS//

function checkResetCardSlot() {
  if (cardSlot > 6) {
    cardSlot = 1;
    // comment or remove below if you want to keep previous value
    document.querySelectorAll('#selection_box .box').forEach(function(box) {
      box.textContent = "";
    })
  }
}

//Generate random small number from array
function genSmallNumber() {
  var smallArray = Array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10);
  var smallNumber = smallArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * smallArray.length)];
  checkResetCardSlot();
  document.getElementById("box" + cardSlot).innerHTML = smallNumber;
  cardSlot++; // update the number here
}

//Generate random large number from array
function genLargeNumber() {
  var largeArray = Array(25, 50, 75, 100);
  var largeNumber = largeArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * largeArray.length)];
  checkResetCardSlot();
  document.getElementById("box" + cardSlot).innerHTML = largeNumber;
  cardSlot++; // and here
}
```

````css
``` * {
  font-family: monospace, 'Courier New';
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, white, grey);
}

::placeholder {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-align: left;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
}

#target_box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #17bef6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 15px 45px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#target_number_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 14px 150px;
  background: black;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  color: yellow;
}

#target {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

#start_button {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 29px 45px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

#start_button:active {
  top: 5px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#selection_box {
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

#box6 {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#whiteboard {
  background: white;
  width: 550px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 240px;
}

#working_area {
  width: 530px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e8eded 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8eded 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  line-height: 27px;
  resize: none;
}

#card_selection_box {
  background: #17bef6;
  height: 120px;
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 405px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#small_number_box {
  float: left;
  width: 275px;
  height: 120px;
}

#large_number_box {
  float: right;
  width: 275px;
  height: 120px;
}

.number_card {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.number_card:active {
  bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#small_number_card {
  position: absolute;
  left: 102.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#large_number_card {
  position: absolute;
  right: 102.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#counter_box {
  background: #17bef6;
  height: 120px;
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 405px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

```
````

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="target_box">
    <div id="target_number_box">
      <span id="target">100</span>
      <div id="start_button">Start</div>
      <div id="selection_box">
        <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box5"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="whiteboard">
    <textarea id="working_area" placeholder="Use this area as a working space..."></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="card_selection_box">
    <div id="small_number_box">
      Small number<br/>(1-10)
      <div class="number_card" id="small_number_card">
        S
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="large_number_box">
      Large number<br/>(25, 50, 75, 100)
      <div class="number_card" id="large_number_card">
        L
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="counter_box">
    <span id="counter_value">30</span>
  </div>

</div>
```